# Getting return value from tkinter button when clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need a tkinter Button to assign a value to a variable, but I can't figure out how. I can't just put the assignment in the button callback function, because that would be local within the callback function and would be lost.  How can I get a value back from the button in my main function?

Here is the code:

```python3
def newfile():
    def create_file(entry):
        file=open(entry.get(0),'w')
        return file
    chdir(askdirectory())
    name=Tk()
    name.title("Name the File?")
    prompt=Label(name, text="Enter name for new file:")
    prompt.grid(row=0)
    e=Entry(name)
    e.grid(row=1)
    e.insert(0, "Untitled")
    create=Button(name, text="Create")
    #Code I want the button to execute: current=create_file(e), name.destroy()
    create.grid(row=2, column=3)
    name.mainloop()
    return current
```

Does anyone know?

Also, I need to be able to retrieve current from the return of `newfile()`.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? It is difficult to see what your problem is without it.

Comment: There it is. The context is that I'm creating a text editor.

Comment: You seem to really have two problems: sending data (`e`) into your callback function, and getting a return value (`file`) out of it.  The API for a button callback function doesn't seem to allow either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `nonlocal current`, you should be able to directly set the current variable within the `create_file` function, as long as current has already been defined, it should work. Remember to put the function call connected to the buttons `command` argument, in a lambda function, so you can give it the argument. In the future, though, really do follow the comments, the whole code could be reorganised to make it seem more sensible...

```
def newfile():
    current = None
    def create_file(entry):
        nonlocal current
        current = open(entry.get(),'w')
        e.master.destroy()
    chdir(askdirectory())
    name=Tk()
    name.title("Name the File?")
    prompt=Label(name, text="Enter name for new file:")
    prompt.grid(row=0)
    e=Entry(name)
    e.grid(row=1)
    e.insert(0, "Untitled")
    create=Button(name, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(e))
    create.grid(row=2, column=3)
    name.mainloop()
    return current
```

Comment: But how do I get current out of `newfile()`? It has to go in a button too, and I need to get current out of it.

Comment: `current` is returned, just store that:
`file = newfile()`

Comment: But the button callback won't let me do that. That's the whole reason I posted this.

Comment: What button, is `newfile()` itself called by a button?

Comment: Then make current global, and define it in the global namespace, instead of returning it... (not very clean but should work)

Comment: I figured out that I could just call `global current` inside `create_file()`, and `newfile()` didn't even have to touch `current`. Thank you for your answer, it helped very much.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a class, in this class define name and current as class variables (self.name and self.current) so I could modify them in a class function without problem.