# Tkinter : Recording entries dynamically created by buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to allow the user to enter as many strings as he wants by clicking some sort of '+' button, and keep the strings in a list. (He enters a first string, clicks '+', another entry box appears, etc.)

For the moment, here's what I've got:

```
def addEntry(window, r, e):
    if r < 9:
        global entries
        entries.append(e.get())
        r += 1
        e = tk.Entry(window)
        e.grid(column=1, row=r)
        add = tk.Button(window, text=' + ', command=lambda:addEntry(window, r, e))
        add.grid(column=2, row=r, sticky=tk.W)
    else:
        errmsg = 'Max. 10 items'
        tk.Label(window, text=errmsg).grid(column=1, row=r+1)


import tkinter as tk

global entries # the main list of strings
entries = []
r = 0 # index for rows ; will not be 0 in the final code as there will be other widgets

win = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(win)
e.grid(column=1, row=r)
add = tk.Button(win, text=' + ', command=lambda:addEntry(win, r, e))
add.grid(column=2, row=r, sticky=tk.W)

win.mainloop()
```

This isn't elegant, and the last entry is not recorded.

I've tried making `entries` a list of Entry() items (not e.get() items), but then I can't access the strings (`TclError: invalid command name ".!entry4"`). I've tried emulating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433269/getting-return-value-from-tkinter-button-when-clicked), which led me to make `entries` a global variable ; I've tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903529/tkinter-dynamically-create-widgets-from-button?rq=1), but I don't fully understand the first answer, and as far as I can tell the strings aren't recorded ; I've tried adapting the class defined in the second answer, but I wasn't able to add buttons dynamically. (I like the idea of making a class, though.) I feel like I should be able to do this, but after a wasting a day on it, might as well ask for help.

Comment: where do you expect the "+" button to be? On a separate row? On the same row as the first entry? Same row as the last? On every row?

Comment: @BryanOakley on the same row as the last, ideally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the *value* in a list, put the actual widget. You should only call the `get` method when you actually need the values.

Also, I strongly recommend you put the entries in a dedicated frame. That way you don't have to worry about what other widgets might be in the window, and you don't have to juggle row and column numbers. Put them in a frame and use `pack` since they are stacked top-to-bottom and all share the same size.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def addEntry(window):
    global entries
    if len(entries) > 10:
        error_message.configure(text="Max. 10 items")
    else:
        error_message.configure(text="")
        entry = tk.Entry(window)
        entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        entries.append(entry)

def show():
    for entry in entries:
        print("=>", entry.get())


entries = []

win = tk.Tk()

entry_frame = tk.Frame(win)
error_message = tk.Label(win)
error_message.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

add = tk.Button(win, text=' + ', command=lambda: addEntry(entry_frame))
show = tk.Button(win, text="Show values", command=show)

add.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NW)
show.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NW)
entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# create the first entry automatically
addEntry(entry_frame)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, only I don't want to print the entries, I want the string to be saved in a list... any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? You can do anything you want with the values: print them, save them to a list, anything you want. The point being, you call `get` when you need the data and not before. Though, if you want the data as soon as they add a new row, just get the value and append it to a list. There's nothing magical going on.